# VB.NET - How do I use a variable in another variables name?

Tags: vb.net

How would I do something similar to this:

```
 Dim amnt As Integer
   For x As Integer = 1 To 6
        If amnt[x] = 0 Then
          btn[x].Enabled = False
        End If
    Next x
```

What I mean is, can I reference a variable by using another variable in the name. For example, if "x" were to be 4, then I want to change the button "btn4" to .Enabled = False, but I also want to be able to change the button that I'm changing properties of. So like

```
 If (variablesName & x) = 0 Then
```

If x is 4 then it should look like this

```
If variablesName4 = 0 Then
```

Comment: Well, what is it.  VB.Net or VBA?  Also, pretty unclear what the question is.

Comment: vba and vb.net are not the same thing. Also, your question makes no sense.

Comment: Sounds like an array `amt()` and `btn()`

Comment: He want to create controls dinamically, no need to downvote, that's not a bad question.

Comment: @phil652 The title has VB.Net, but you keep the VBA tag?

Comment: Arrays, Collections, or Dictionaries?  What are `amnt` and `btn`? I can guess, but it's better if you ask a good question with enough detail in the first place :)

Comment: You should use parentheses, a.k.a. round brackets, `(` and `)` to access the elements of an array, not square brackets `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean evaluating a variable by supplying it's name as a string - then this cannot be done in VBA.

For example:

```
Dim testVar As Integer
Dim v As String

v = "Var"
testVar = 5

Debug.Print test & v '// error
Debug.Print "test" & v '// prints "testVar" as a string
Debug.Print "testVar" '// prints "testVar" as a string
Debug.Print testVar '// prints "5" <~~ only way it can be done
```

However, for some controls, and some other items - you can access the parent collection and supply a string value to get the correct index. So something like:

```
For i = 1 To 10
    '// Will set checkboxes 1 to 10 to be checked
    myForm.Controls("Checkbox" & i).Checked = True
Next
```

As it stands - it's too broad a question to give a definitive answer, but depending on the kind of objects you are working with you may be able to access a parent collection in this way.